# Uploading File Images with AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I am attempting to create an upload document which will upload a profile picture. I am having trouble capturing the data from the `changePicture` form which only has an input for the images and a submit. I have never used the `FormData` object to date, so I am still learning around this. Any guidance would be useful.

See my HTML

```
<form id="changePicture" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Update Your Profile Picture</label>
            <input type="file" id="profilePic" class="form-control" name="profilePic">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="id">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="updateProfileBtn" class="btn btn-success float-right">Upload Image</button>
 </form>
```

Here is my AJAX code:

```
function updateProfilePic(){
$("#changePicture").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#spinner").show();

    setTimeout(function(){
        $.ajax({
           url: "../ajax/admin/updateProfilePic.php",
           type: "POST",
           data: new FormData(this),   
           cache: false,
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           success: function(result){
               $("#spinner").hide();
               $("#changePicture").append(result);

               setTimeout(function(){
                $("#changePicture").slideDown();
               }, 1500);
           }
        });
    }, 3000);
});    
}
```

The PHP file at this moment only echos out "Working" to see it accesses the page alright, which it does. However, when I attempt to locate the file through a variable nothing has been sent and returns `undefined index`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the setTimeout?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you wrapping your AJAX call in a

```
setTimeout(function() {..})
```

?

By doing this, you cannot simply write `new FormData(this)`, because the `this` context does not refer to the form that you are looking for.

Try executing the code without the timeout, or try storing the form data in a global variable

Edit: Example added:

```
var myFormData;

function updateProfilePic(){
$("#changePicture").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#spinner").show();
    myFormData = new FormData(this);

    setTimeout(function(){
       $.ajax({
           url: "../ajax/admin/updateProfilePic.php",
           type: "POST",
           data: myFormData, 
           ....
```

Comment: He might need the timeout. Perhaps he could use `var that = this` in the outer function.

Comment: Like I said, `.. or try storing the form data in a global variable`

Answer (score 1):

this will be undefined because it's inside ajax's scope

Try:

```
me = this; 

$.ajax({ 
url: "../ajax/admin/updateProfilePic.php", 
type: "POST", 
data: new FormData(me),
...
```

As, for me, when using ajax I always prefer to base64encode the image and pass it as a JSON to PHP but i guess that's a personal preference...